# Multi-client udp server in c

Tags: c, server, udp

I'm trying to code a server which on message from client goes through the database to see if a file with the same name exist. If it does server will then send the music info whilst reading it.

I've implemented the version where one client works, but for some reason, it looks like some messages that should be received from the childs are received with the parent protocole.

Here's the code I've done so far. The version with only one client works just fine.
It's only when I started doing the fork to make it so that every child only has one client to interact to that it started bugging.

It looks like I should only have one rcvfrom but I don't really know how it would work. Cause that would mean the parent would be the one to send all clients responses to the correct child. Also the child would have to know when to wait for server response.

I'm sure there a smarter way to do it, any ideas ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "audio.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

void readMusic(char *musicName, int serverFd, struct sockaddr_in client);

void readMusic(char *musicName, int serverFd, struct sockaddr_in client)
{
    // read files
    int sample_rate, sample_size, channels;

    int fdRead = aud_readinit(musicName, &sample_rate, &sample_size, &channels);
    if (fdRead < 0)
    {
        perror("Error while opening file.");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in clientTmp;

    // sends sample_rate sample_size and channels to client
    char buf[1024];
    int params[3];
    params[0] = sample_rate;
    params[1] = sample_size;
    params[2] = channels;
    int res = sendto(serverFd, params, sizeof(params), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if (res < 0)
    {
        perror("Error while sending sample parameters");
        exit(1);
    }
    // config timeout
    int nb;
    fd_set read_set;
    struct timeval timeout;

    socklen_t len, flen;
    flen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    char resclient[1024];
    // read and send music info to the client
    while (read(fdRead, buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0)
    {
        res = sendto(serverFd, buf, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        if (res < 0)
        {
            perror("Error while sending music buffer");
            exit(1);
        }

        FD_ZERO(&read_set);          /* Clear the read_set */
        FD_SET(serverFd, &read_set); /* Wait until fd is ready for reading */
        timeout.tv_sec = 0;          /* 0 seconds */
        timeout.tv_usec = 500000;    /* 500000 micro-seconds = 0.5 second */
        nb = select(serverFd + 1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if (nb < 0)
        {
            perror("error while setting timeout");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (nb == 0)
        {
            
            puts("timeout exception");
            res = sendto(serverFd, buf, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)); //sends last info that was lost
            if (res < 0)
            {
                perror("Error while sending music buffer");
                exit(1);
            }
            FD_CLR(serverFd, &read_set);
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(serverFd, &read_set))
        {
            len = recvfrom(serverFd, resclient, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clientTmp, &flen);
            if (len < 0)
            {
                perror("Error while receiving answer from client");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    close(fdRead);
    char endMsg[1024] = "END";
    res = sendto(serverFd, endMsg, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if (res < 0)
    {
        perror("Error while sending end of music message");
        exit(1);
    }

}

int main()
{
    // get hostname
    char hostname[1024];
    hostname[1023] = '\0';
    gethostname(hostname, 1023);

    // CREATION SOCKET UDP ON PORT 1234
    int fd, err;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        perror("Error while creating socket.");
        exit(1);
    }

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(1234);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    err = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if (err < 0)
    {
        perror("Error while binding");
        exit(1);
    }
    puts("Binding done");

    printf("Server %s opérationnel\n", hostname);
    printf("Server adress : %s\n", inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr));

    pid_t pidCurrent;
    char msg[1024];
    socklen_t len, flen;
    struct sockaddr_in from;
    while (1)
    {
        // receive first message from client
        
        flen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        sleep(2);
        len = recvfrom(fd, msg, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, &flen);
        if (len < 0)
        {
            perror("Error while receiving client connection");
        }
        if(strcmp(msg,"OK") == 0){ //if message was supposed to be received by the child
            printf("stolen message: %s\n",msg);
            continue;
        }
        
        printf("Received %d bytes from host %s port %d: %s\n", len, inet_ntoa(from.sin_addr), ntohs(from.sin_port), msg);

        // multiple client
        pidCurrent = fork();
        if (pidCurrent < 0)
        {
            perror("Error while Forking");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (pidCurrent == 0)
        { // childs
            // reads music to client
            readMusic(msg, fd, from);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        { // parent
            // zombie childs
            int stat; // child status
            while ((pidCurrent = waitpid(-1, &stat, WNOHANG)) > 0)
            {
                printf("child %d terminated\n", pidCurrent);
            }
        }
    }
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My ***guess*** is that the messages the clients send do not include the string null-terminator character `'\0'`.

That means any use of the array `msg` as a string will lead to *undefined behavior* as functions try to find the non-existing null-terminator and possibly go out of bounds of the array.

You need to add the terminator yourself (error checking omitted):

```
// Only receive up to one byte less than the size of the array,
// to be sure that it will fit the null-terminator we add
len = recvfrom(fd, msg, sizeof msg - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, &flen);

msg[len] = '\0';  // Make sure the array is properly null-terminated as a string should be
```

Even if the clients send the null-terminator, it's a good habit to always add it anyway. You never know if or when a badly coded client will forget to send it.

Comment: Just tested that, it doesn't change the problem, though you're probably right about it being better.